# Can't export release build / compile for Adobe AIR 1.0

Tags: apache-flex, air, flexbuilder

I opened up an old project in Flex Builder 3 which runs on [Adobe AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) 1.0. I believe it was originally written in Flex Builder 2. When I try to run the Adobe Air application, nothing happens. When I try to export a release build, I get this error:

http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.0">

If I change the main-app.xml file to use the 1.5 version of the namespace, it builds fine. Unfortunately, the clients environment runs on 1.0. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. You can only compile AIR 1.0 files with an older Flex SDK. Head over to the Adobe Flex site, and download an older SDK. http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3 I wanted to the 3.0.3 build, but the download was giving a 404, so I used 3.0.0. Under compile settings in Flex builder, add the new SDK, and then use that for a build. It works after that. It's a real shame they didn't handle this error better in Flex Builder. Right now it's a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest answer, without a ton of support steps and questions (not the least of which for me would be -- what is the image/error? I'm behind a ridiculously-high-security firewall + proxy server and can't see it), would be to start a new 1.5 AIR project with the same name.  Then copy the fewest number of files as possible... the main windowedApp file + the style and component files, avoiding project config files.

You might get yourself in trouble if you wanted to keep the client's development environment as 1.0 (which is what I assume you meant by "Unfortunately, the clients environment runs on 1.0.").... make sure not to mix your project config files (.flexProperties, the app.xml files, etc.) and you should be cool.